# Converting label into textbox in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, force.com

I am creating a page.where we search a record based on the given id.the record is displayed along with a edit and save button.The data is displayed onto label.On the click on edit button the label should be changed into textbox prepopulated with the data.how do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set boolean flag true in constructor initially.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstX}" var="x" >         
          <apex:column headerValue="A" >
              <apex:inputField value="{!x.aField}"  rendered="{!NOT(flag)}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!x.aField}"  rendered="{!flag}"/>
          </apex:column>   
          <apex:column headerValue="B" >
              <apex:inputField value="{!x.bField}" rendered="{!NOT(flag)}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!x.bField}"  rendered="{!flag}"/>
          </apex:column>         
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

you can set flag true/false accordingly on EDIT/SAVE button method.