# how input field can converted into output field in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

how we can hide input fields of a custom object on a button click and output field comes in place of input field with inserted data using apex class and visualforce page?

Comment: you can refer this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28034/converting-label-into-textbox-in-visualforce/28036#28036 and implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.FirstName}" rendered="NOT(showReadMode)"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!acc.FirstName}" rendered="showReadMode"/>
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

When ever you click on button, call you apex class where you can set a two flags say f1 and f2. Now in your VF page for input field rendered set as f1 and for output field set rendered as f2.

Remember that by default f1 should be true and f2 should be false, on click of the button swap the flags. hope this will help you.